# Python, multiprocessing.pool took about the same amount of time as a for loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to use python to process some large data sets from several data stations. My idea is to use multiprocessing.pool to assign each CPU the data from a single station, since the data from each station are independent from each other.

However, it seems that my calculation time does not really go down, comparing to single for loop.

Here is part of my code:

```
#function calculating the square of each data point, and taking the cumulative sum
def get_cumdd(data):
    #if not isinstance(data, list):
    #    data = [data]
    dd = np.zeros((len(data),1))
    cum_dd = np.zeros((len(data),1))
    for i in range(len(data)):
        dd[i] = data[i]**2
    cum_dd=np.cumsum(dd)
    return cum_dd

#parallelization between each station 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n_proc = np.min([mp.cpu_count(),nstation]) #nstation = 10
    p = mp.Pool(processes=int(n_proc)) 
    result = p.map(get_cumdd,data)
    p.close()
    p.join()
cum_dd = np.zeros((nstation,len(data[0])))
for i in range(nstation):
    cum_dd[i] = result[i].T
```

I do not use chunksize because cum_dd takes the summation of all the previous data^2. I am essentially dividing my data into 10 equal pieces because there is no communication between processes. I wonder if I missed anything here.

My data has 2 million points per station per day, and I need to process years of data.

Comment: How much data are you dealing with? How long does each method take? If the data is processed quite quickly you may even see a *decrease* in performance since starting each additional process has some overhead.

Comment: My data is about 2 million points per station per day, and I have years of data. mp.pool took about an hour to process a day, and for loop took roughly 75 minutes.

Comment: Also, when posting Python code, please make absolutely sure your formatting and in particular indentation is correct.

Comment: You're probably better off using shared memory. Most likely you're spending too much overhead on I/O. Put all the data in one place that all processes can access instead of passing data between processes, which is what multiprocessing will do by default. You can Google how to use shared memory for multiprocessing in Python, for starters.

Comment: Another point I would probably make is that the way you're using Numpy almost completely eliminates any benefit of doing so. Instead of creating explicit `for` loops in Python you want to read your raw data into Numpy arrays in the first place, and use Numpy's vectorized operations over the array. Everything in your `get_cumdd` function can be done purely by Numpy without making very slow element-wise operations in Python. I can expand on this more below if you're not sure what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

NumPy already implements efficient parallel processing on CPUs and GPUs. The processing algorithms use Single Instruction Multiple Data (SIMD) instructions.

By pooling computations manually, you are reducing the efficiency. You can improve performance by vectorizing your explicit `for` loop.

See the video below for more information about vectorization.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qsIrQi0fzbY

If you are having difficulties, I will be around for updates or help. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't address your multiprocessing question directly, but (as Ugur MULUK and Iguananaut mention) I think your `get_cumdd` function is inefficient. Numpy provides [`np.cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html). Reimplementing your function I get more than 1000x speedup for an array with 10k elements. With 100k elements it's about 7000x faster. With 2M elements I didn't bother to let it finish.

```
# your function
def cum_dd(data):
    #if not isinstance(data, list):
    #    data = [data]
    dd = np.zeros((len(data),1))
    cum_dd = np.zeros((len(data),1))
    for i in range(len(data)):
        dd[i] = data[i]**2
        cum_dd[i]=np.sum(dd[0:i])
    return cum_dd

# numpy implementation
def cum_dd2(data):
    # adding an axis to match the shape of the output of your cum_dd function
    return np.cumsum(data**2)[:, np.newaxis]
```

For 2e6 points this implementation takes ~11ms on my computer. I think that's about 30 seconds for 10 years of data for a single station.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot for all the comments and answers! After applying vectorization and pooling, I reduced the calculation time from one hour to 3 second (10*1.7 million data points). I have my code here in case anyone is interested,

```
def get_cumdd(data):
    #if not isinstance(data, list):
    #    data = [data]
    dd = np.zeros((len(data),1))
    for i in range(len(data)):
        dd[i] = data[i]**2
    cum_dd=np.cumsum(dd)
    return dd,cum_dd

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n_proc = np.min([mp.cpu_count(),nstation])
    p = mp.Pool(processes=int(n_proc))       
    result = p.map(CC.get_cumdd,d)
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

I'm not using shared memory Queue because all my processes are independent from each other.